# PHP - links and modification of links

Tags: php, wordpress, web, hyperlink

Well, I'm editing WP theme and creating network so I need to get url and modificate it for use in `<a></a>`tags.
I created function called **urlbg();** and on normal domain (like www.xyz.com) it works but in subdomain it don't work.
I called functions in `<a></a>` tags like so:

```
<a href="'. urlbg( 'ark') . '" title="ARK: Survival Evolved"><img src="'. content_url() .'/themes/newsgamer/images/ark.png"></a>
```

Problem is, in normal domain (like www.xyz.com) when i use functions eg. **urlbg( 'ASD' );** i get **ASD.xyz.com** and thats what i want, BUT in other way when i use the same code in subdomain (like foo.xyz.com) and when i called function in **urlbg( 'ASD' );**`<a></a>` tags, i get **foo.xyz.com/ASD.** (but need **ASD.xyz.com** ).
Sorry for my bad English I hope you'll understand me and know whats my problem.

Code of function urlbg();

```
   function urlbg($prefix){
                $siteUrl = get_site_url(); 
                $url = str_replace("http://", "https://", "". $prefix . ".", $siteUrl);
                return $url;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function urlbg($prefix){
    $siteUrl = get_site_url();
    $url = 'https://'.$prefix.strstr($siteUrl, '.');
    return $url;
}
```

Assuming you will always have this pattern http(s)://something_to_replace.something_to_keep.